# Is there a function or script I can use to change the background color of a cell in google sheets to display its hex code?

Tags: google-sheets, background-color

I have tried several codes that I find on here to see if that resolves my problems they keep reaching a different error. Many or "out of range" errors. What I am looking to do is take the background color and convert it to its hexcode so I may better conditionally format it. I have already used an extension to pixelate an image but I can't access the colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the hex code this way

```
function hexCode(){
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1')
  console.log (r.getBackgrounds()[0][0]);
}
```